# How to filter a dataframe and assign a value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to assign an object(it could be a list,tuple, string) to a specific cell in a dataframe, but it does not work. I am filtering first and then trying to assign the value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0vsI.png)

I am using df.loc[df['name']=='aagicampus'].reset_index(drop=True).at[0,'words']='test'

The expected result is something like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ8TD.png)

It works if I create a copy of the dataframe, but I must keep the original dataframe to iterate later over a list and perform this procedure many times.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: make minimal and reproducible example by code or text, not image https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by first getting the indices of the row(s) that you want to change, and then setting cells at one of those locations to the desired value.

This code gets the locations of rows that satisfy your condition of df['name'] == 'aagicampus

```
locations = df.index[df['name'] == 'aagicampus']
```

then you just .loc on locations[0] to change the first row that satisfies the condition. Here it is all together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['something','aagicampus','something'], 'words':['unchanged', 'unchanged', 'unchanged'] })
locations = df.index[df['name'] == 'aagicampus']
df.words.loc[locations[0]] = 'CHANGED'
df.head()
```

this will return a table:

```
    name    words
0   something   unchanged
1   aagicampus  CHANGED
2   something   unchanged
```

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry for the images.